# Add image to Constructive Solid Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was at the following site http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ looking at three.js examples and came across the Constructive Solid Geometry example. This tutorial by example shows how to  subtract a cube from a sphere. The example uses THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();. I would like to add an image to the sphere before subtracting the cube from it. I'm going to list the code below.

Code from the example

```
var materialNormal = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1 );
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry );
var cubeBSP = new ThreeBSP( cubeMesh );

var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 60, 32, 32 );
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry );
var sphereBSP = new ThreeBSP( sphereMesh );

// Example #2 - Sphere subtract Cube
var newBSP = sphereBSP.subtract( cubeBSP );
var newMesh = newBSP.toMesh( materialNormal );
newMesh.position.set(180, 60, 0);
scene.add( newMesh );
```

To achive my goal of adding an image I altered the code slightly. Changing materialNormal to materialBasic.

```
var spherImg2 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/roomDoorsb.jpg' );
var materialBasic = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: spherImg2, side:THREE.DoubleSide } );

var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 1, 1, 1 );
var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeometry );
var cubeBSP = new ThreeBSP( cubeMesh );

var sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 60, 32, 32 );
var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry );
var sphereBSP = new ThreeBSP( sphereMesh );

// Example #2 - Sphere subtract Cube
var newBSP = sphereBSP.subtract( cubeBSP );
var newMesh = newBSP.toMesh( materialBasic );
newMesh.position.set(180, 60, 0);
scene.add( newMesh );
```

The remaining sections of the sphere do not display the desired image. There just showing grey. Also I would like to note that the ThreeCSG.js file from the example was throwing an error. I think line 215 was out of date so I replaced it.

It was

```
mesh.rotation.setEulerFromRotationMatrix( this.matrix );
```

And I changed it to

```
mesh.quaternion.setFromRotationMatrix( this.matrix );
```

I would be very grateful for any help received. Thanks

Comment: @Lee Stemkoski I have a question about one of the examples from your site and was wondering if I can get your opinion.

Comment: (1) See https://github.com/kraag22/csg-wrapper, it may be of interest. (2) Your geometry needs valid UVs. Are they all ( 0, 0 )?

Comment: I haven't set the UVs manually. Normally I stick to the predefined geometry's of three.js so this is my first time dealing with UVs at all. I'm not sure how to check the value of the UVs. Any tips on how I should proceed.

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect. `mesh.geometry.faceVertexUVs[0]`. Compare the values with those of `CubeGeometry` and `SphereGeometry`.

Comment: Ok so I tried to change the code up a little bit. I changed "var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry );" to "var sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/roomDoorsb.jpg' ) } ) );" I figured if i applied the texture before the subtraction than maby the UVs would get set automatically but no dice. I checked the values of the UVs. Both CubeGeometry and SphereGeometry have values between 0 and 1 like there suppose to but newMesh just lists values of ( 0, 0 ) like you guessed.

Comment: I looked at https://github.com/kraag22/csg-wrapper/blob/master/ThreeCSG.js and saw how the UVs were set. If the same is happening to you, you need to figure out how to retain or reset them.

Comment: Yea I was thinking the same thing. As always thanks for the advice.